# Remove characters between html tags and split into multiple strings

Tags: r

Below you can see some example strings and what I would like to receive. I know how to remove HTML tags. However, I want to first remove some characters between certain tags and the split the string into multiple strings. All characters between the `<zt>` and `</zt>` should be removed. I bet this would be super easy, however, I'm unfamiliar with manipulating strings and after many hours of searching and trying, I have not managed to do it by myself.

Thank you for your kind help.

```r
example_str <- "<tx><zt>some title</zt><zt>some subtitle</zt>
<p>Here comes the actual text that I want to keep.</p>
<zt>some title</zt><zt>some subtitle</zt>
<p>Here comes the actual text that I want to keep.</p></tx>"

#Expected string after first cleaning
#"<tx><p>Here comes the actual text that I want to keep.</p>
#<p>Here comes the actual text that I want to keep.</p></tx>"

#Expected string vector after 2nd cleaning
#c("Here comes the actual text that I want to keep.","Here comes the actual text that I want to keep.")
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Try `str_remove_all(example_str, "\\<zt\\>[^</]+\\</zt>")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(str_remove_all(example_str, "\\<zt\\>[^</]+\\</zt>"), 
   "(?<=\\>)([^</\n]+)")[[1]]
```

-output

```
[1] "Here comes the actual text that I want to keep."
[2] "Here comes the actual text that I want to keep."
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there also a possibility to apply this method for an entire df, so that the number of rows increases? Kinda like with `pivot_longer`?

Comment: @NickGlättli If you have multiple columns, then you could either use `across` to loop over the columns and apply the function or use reshape those columns to long format with `pivot_longer` and apply the function on the reshaped value column

Comment: I do not have multiple columns. Just multiple rows that contain several texts within them (like above). However, I want to have one row for one text. So I want to extract all texts from the rows and have one for each.

Comment: @NickGlättli If your column name is `col1`, perhaps you want `sapply(str_extract_all(str_remove_all(yourdf$col1, "\\<zt\\>[^</]+\\</zt>"), 
   "(?<=\\>)([^</\n]+)"), function(x) paste(x, collapse = " "))`

Comment: Then I lose all information from the other columns, though...

Comment: @NickGlättli I meant `yourdf$col1 <- sapply(...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253351/discussion-between-nick-glattli-and-akrun).